# Restoring the IntelliJ IDEA "Project tab"

Tags: ide, intellij-idea

By default the IntelliJ IDEA interface contains the following tabs/panels:

- Project (tabbed to the left)
- Structure (tabbed to the left)
- Commander (tabbed to the right)
- Ant Build (tabbed to the right)
- IDEtalk (tabbed to the right)
- Maven Projects (tabbed to the right)
- Data Sources (tabbed to the right)
- TODO (tabbed at the bottom)
- Web Preview (tabbed at the bottom)

Due to some fiddling around with the settings in one of my projects I've managed to remove all tabs/panels but the following:

- IDEtalk (tabbed to the right)
- Maven Projects (tabbed to the right)
- Data Sources (tabbed to the right)
- Web Preview (tabbed at the bottom)

I'm running IntelliJ IDEA 8.1.

Question:

- **How do I the Project tab and the rest of the lost tabs?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Procedure to recover all tabs:

1. Backup the "damaged" project
2. Create a new project using the same project name as the damaged project
3. Restore the backup of the damaged project, but copy over the `.iml` and `.ipr` files which were created when creating the fresh project in the previous step
4. Open the recovered project and then used `File > Synchronize` to pick up all files in the project
5. The project and all tabs are now restored. Done!

The above procedure has been tested and is known to work.

Comment: Another option seems to be to simply remove the PROJECTNAME.iws file and restart IDEA. The .iws file will be automatically created and the problem disappears.

Answer (score 25):

The (infuriating) answer is that you just need to click the icon at the very bottom left of your screen. Then the project and other tabs will magically reappear. UX #fail

Comment: dont think this answers the quesiton, but very useful info. thanx!

Comment: Totally a UX#Fail

Answer (score 0):

go to `View` -> `Tool Windows` and click `Project` or simply press `command + 1` on mac.